# How to add rows from two select statement in my sql?

Tags: mysql, select, addition

In MySQL, if I have two select statements `A` and `B` and both returns a column of integers

For example:

`A` returns

```
4
6
20
8
2
10
15
```

`B` returns

```
3
5
8
13
10
15
80
58
```

How can I combine them into a table and filter out all duplicates (remove from `B` if it's in `A`), like this:

```
4
6
20
8
2
10
15
3
5
13
80
58
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tables are inherently unordered.  The SQL operation for combining values from tables is `union`:

```
select A.*
from A
union
select B.*
from B;
```

Note that the ordering of the values is most likely going to change.

EDIT:

If you want to get the values from "A" before the remaining values from "B", you can do that with:

```
select col
from (select A.col, 'A' as which
      from A
      union all
      select B.col, 'B'
      from B
      where not exists (select 1 from A where A.col = B.col)
     ) ab
order by which;
```

Comment: So there's no way to keep the ordering from A the same, and just remove the ones from B that are in A?

Comment: @omega . . . Unless you have a field like an id or creation date, then the answer is "no".  SQL tables are inherently unordered (they represent sets).  There is no ordering, so it cannot be preserved.

Comment: The values above, are id's from the table. Does that make a difference, so for each table A, and B, their values will be unique.